# std::istream& operator >> and own vector class

Tags: c++, class, vector, overloading

i am trying to write a vector class with a method that automaticly creates a vector without given size:

```
    std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& is, Vector& v )
{
    /* working (but not mine) version i am basing on
    int size;
    is >> size;
    v.create( size );
    for( int i=0; i<v.size(); i++ ) is >> v.m_pBuf[i];
    return is;
    */

    int size;
    std::string strBuf;

    //std::istream& tmp = is; //copy doesn't exist!
    //is.ignore(0,'\n');
    getline(is, strBuf,'\n');

    size = (strBuf.length()+1)/2;
    std::cout << "Size of buffer = " <<size<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "bufrer = " <<strBuf<< std::endl;

    v.create( size );

    for( int i=0; i<v.size()*2; i++ ) {
            if (!(i%2)){                              // to avoid spaces
                    double vec = (double)strBuf[i]-48;
                    //std::cout << "vec = " <<vec<< std::endl;
                    v.m_pBuf[i]= vec;

            }
    }

    return is;

}
```

but it crashes with an error:

```
/*
input:
    Vector x(3);
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2;
    x[2] = 3;

    Vector y(x);
    Vector z;
        std::cout << "x=" << x << "y=" << y << "z=" << z;
        std::cout << "Podaj wektor z: ";
        std::cin  >> z;
        std::cout << "z=" << z;
output:
    x=[ 1 2 3 ]
    y=[ 1 2 3 ]
    z=[ ]
    Insert a vector z: 2 3 4 5 6 7
    Size of buffer = 6
    buffer = 2 3 4 5 6 7
    z=[ 2 0 3 0 4 0 ]

    Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 44.491 s
    Press any key to continue.

        */
```

Is there any trick to freeze my 'is' variable or to rewrite input stream? What here is wrong al all?

Comment: The code to calculate the size of the input vector won't work if you have values larger than 9 in it, or negative values.

Comment: As for your problem, look at that loop condition again, and think about how many times it will loop and therefore write to `v.m_pBuf[i]`. Also read about [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which will happen when you, for example, write beyond the limits of allocated memory.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I'll think of another solution

Comment: I suggest you read about [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream), with that you can simply loop using the standard input operator `>>` to read e.g. integers from a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your for loop, you are indexing `v.m_pBuf` based on `i` where you are skipping all odd `i`. Thus you are trying to acess locations `0, 2, 4, ...` which implies you are going past your allocated space. Try using a different index variable and increment it inside the `if` condition.

Your code will look like this :

```
for( int i=0, j=0; i<v.size()*2; i++ ) {
        if (!(i%2)){                              // to avoid spaces
                double vec = (double)strBuf[i]-48;
                //std::cout << "vec = " <<vec<< std::endl;
                v.m_pBuf[j]= vec;
                j++; // notice j increments only for even positions.
        }
}
```